# Julia, Gtk: What are the kwargs in open_dialog_native function?

Tags: julia, gtk

Does anybody know what the kwargs are in the open_dialog_native function?
I know one is `select_multiple` from the docs, but can't find any other info on Google.

Answer (score 0):

The `kwargs` are directly passed to `GTKFileChooserNative`.
Hence you can find the full list at the GTK documentation (see the *Properties* section at https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.FileChooserNative.html )

Hence for an example you can do in Julia (note that dashes from Gtk docs `-` are replaced by underscores `_`):

```
open_dialog_native("Select file";modal=true,accept_label="YES!",cancel_label="STOP!")
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou. I was looking for kwargs that would allow setting the default folder to open on and also the filename to print in the 'File_name' box; but alas it seems that from the docs you referenced, they're not available.